# How SPARQL endpoints provide data in different formats

Tags: sparql, endpoint, triplestore

I am creating a SPARQL endpoint and I want to ask that how SPARQL endpoints provide data in different formats i.e. JSON, RDF/XML, N3 etc. Do they store data in all these formats or there is an API to convert data in all these formats?

Thanks
Regards,
Umair Qudus

Comment: they store the data in a canonical, internal format like any other database. export and serialization of the data is then done on demand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
is there any standard library to export data in multiple formats?
e.g. in dbpedia( http://dbpedia.org/sparql ) we have the option for viewing results in different formats.

Comment: Well, doesn't this depend on the programming language of your implemented triple store? maybe you didn't understand my previous comment, but the idea is that your triple store has a very efficient data structure for the triples and after you computed the query result, you write your own exporter for each language - indeed you could use some existing library, nevertheless you have to map from your data structure to the internal format of the library then first.

Comment: The [DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) is delivered by an instance of [Virtuoso RDBMS](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), which was an early, possibly the first, RDF datastore to directly support multiple serializations for SPARQL query results. Even today, some datastores only output their own preferred serialization, leaving it to the client app to handle any desired transformation.

Answer (score -3):

Usually the data is stored as follows,

```
RDF (N3, turttle, XML)
```

It's about Linked Data!, and the endpoint has the service to ask for the query result in different formats:

```
RDF, cxv, XML
```